# Excel: Checking for errors in an IF statement

Tags: excel

I am trying to write an excel if statement. I am new to using all the extra functionality Excel has. I am using a function called `importXML()`. I am trying to check whether a function I am using generates a "#VALUE!" error as follows:

```
if(
   importXML(B1,C1)!="#VALUE!" //check if no error generated, 
   importXML(B1,C1)//if no error is generated, use these cells in the function
   importXML(A1,C1)//else use these cells in the function
)
```

Is this possible? Am I using excels if statement correctly to check for errors?

Comment: Is this in VBA or in a spreadsheet?

Comment: Not used excel for a while but try, `IF(importXML(B1,C1)<>"#VALUE!", importXML(B1,C1), importXML(A1,C1))`

Comment: @Ash thanks for the reply, what is the '<>' for if you don't mind me asking :)

Comment: `<>` is the old style "not equal to".

Comment: importXML looks like a UDF, why not do your error handling in your code?

Comment: If you're using 2007 or newer you can use =iferror(function, valueiferror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(importXML(B1,C1)),value_if_true,value_if_false)
```

[ISERROR Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php)

Comment: @mhz you're welcome.  the `iferror` function is also very handy in your arsenal, but less portable if your users may have older versions of excel.